# Exact number of Rdds in window operation in Spark streaming

Tags: spark-streaming

I want to use window operation in spark streaming. Does it has any guarantee that each window slide with take in more (slideDuration/batchDuration) number of Rdds?

```
For example, If I set batchDuration=10s in streamingContext, and slideDuration=30s in window operation. 

stream.window(60s, slideDuration).forEachRDD(**unionRdd** -> .....)
```

Does the unionRdd above will contain 3 more batch in each run?

Answer (score 1):

The exact number of RDDs in a window can be represented by the following function:

```
t: Time elapsed
W: Window duration
S: Sliding duration
B: Batch interval 

if t%S ==0 AND S%B == 0 AND W%B==0
    if t>=W
        N := W/B
    else
        N := t/B
else N := null // no rdd under processing.
```